# Read images and process them in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to opencv and python. Need an advice. For example I have two videos: First one is 2 minute video: there is shown a billboard with commercials on it which stands in the city, with cars and people on background, and the second one is 10 seconds commercial which is on this billboard. I want to find if 10 seconds commercial is inside the 2 minutes video. To obtain this goal I am about to compare frames in different videos. 
First of all I take first video and split on frames, then I need to select this billboard from frames( to do this I subtract background). My problem is this process doesn't work. I cannot load frames and crap this object from there.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from glob import glob

os.chdir('C:/Python27/Projects/VidComp/asd') 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Python27/Projects/VidComp/asd/test_video.mov')
cap.isOpened()

count = 0
success = True
while success:
  success,image = cap.read()
if count % 91 == 0:
    cv2.imwrite("image%d.jpg" % count, image) 
count += 1

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

#Load the Image
 for fn in glob('*.jpg'):
 img0 = cv2.imread(fn)

 height, width = imgo.shape[:2]

 #Create a mask holder
 mask = np.zeros(imgo.shape[:2],np.uint8)

 #Grab Cut the object
 bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
 fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

  #Hard Coding the Rect The object must lie within this rect.
  rect = (750,500,450,950)
  cv2.grabCut(imgo,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
  mask = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
  img1 = imgo*mask[:,:,np.newaxis]

  #Get the background
  background = imgo - img1

  #Change all pixels in the background that are not black to white
  background[np.where((background > [0,0,0]).all(axis = 2))] = [255,255,255]

   #Add the background and the image
   final = background + img1

     #To be done - Smoothening the edges

    #cv2.imshow('image', img1 )
     cv2.imwrite('*.jpg',img1 )

    cv2.waitKey(0)

    k = cv.waitKey(0)

    if k==27:
         cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Would be very glad if you help me how to solve it.

Comment: It's unclear, to me at least, what you are trying to do here. You say you want to compare frames in different videos - with what? to what end? Do you want to compare every frame in one video with a frame in another video? What do your videos look like?

Comment: Hey. Next step I want to compute phash for frames and compare hashes. But now I cannot read all frames to crop them.

Comment: I am still unclear on a) what you want to do, and b) what the current problem is. Please click `edit` under your question and add a proper description to your question of what you want to do overall, and what the current problem is. Are there error messages? Is it too slow? Why are you even writing JPEG images out to disk - you can load frames from the videos and compute hashes on them as you go without JPEG encoding and disk I/O.